# Query syntax issue in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement one-to-many association using spring data JPA,
My model class Users.java is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
public String username;
public String password;
public Integer privid;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pid")
private Collection<Privillages> priviJoin;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name = "username")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
@Column(name = "password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "privid")
public Integer getPrivid() {
    return privid;
}
public void setPrivid(Integer privid) {
    this.privid = privid;
}

public Collection<Privillages> getPriviJoin() {
    return priviJoin;
}
public void setPriviJoin(Privillages priviJoin) {
    this.priviJoin = (Collection<Privillages>) priviJoin;
}

public Users() {
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Users[id=%d, username='%s', password='%s']", id, 
username, password);
}
}
```

And Privillages.java is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "privillages")
public class Privillages implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer id;

public String pname;


@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "pid", referencedColumnName = "privid")
public Users pid;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "pname")
public String getPname() {
    return pname;
}
public void setPname(String pname) {
    this.pname = pname;
}

@Column(name = "pid")
public Users getPid() {
    return pid;
}
public void setPid(Users pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public Privillages(){
} 
}
```

And my view is,

```
<div th:each= "user: ${joinData}">

        <span th:text="${user.pname}">
        </span>
        <span th:text="${user.username}">
        </span>
    </div>
```

I need to fetch username from Users and pname from Privillages. By combining i need to display. Now I am using below query in my repository, Ie,

```
@Query("select u from Users ug inner join ug.priviJoin u")
List<Users> findByUsername();
```

And I need to select username from one and pname from another table,as mentioned in above. How I need to change my query?

Comment: I did not got any useful suggestion for selecting syntax from two tables, When using queries only getting datas from single table.How I can fetch data from multiple table ? Can anyone help me to solve this issue?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing this issue for two reasons.

1. The JPQL Query is not valid.
2. You have not created an association between your entities that the underlying JPQL query can utilize.

When performing a join in JPQL you must ensure that an underlying association between the entities attempting to be joined exists. In your example, you are missing an association between the Users and Privillages entities.In order to create this association we must add an Privillages field within the Users class and establish the appropriate JPA Mapping. I have attached the source for Users below.

**Users.java**

```
 @Entity
        @Table(name = "users")
        public class Users implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
        public String username;
        public String password;
        public Integer privid;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pid")
        private Collection<Privillages> priviJoin;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @OneToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name="pname")
        private Privillages privillages;

        @Column(name = "username")
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        @Column(name = "password")
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Column(name = "privid")
        public Integer getPrivid() {
            return privid;
        }
        public void setPrivid(Integer privid) {
            this.privid = privid;
        }

        public Collection<Privillages> getPriviJoin() {
            return priviJoin;
        }
        public void setPriviJoin(Privillages priviJoin) {
            this.priviJoin = (Collection<Privillages>) priviJoin;
        }

        public Users() {
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Users[id=%d, username='%s', password='%s']", id, 
        username, password);
        }
        /**
         * @return the pvs
         */
        public Privillages getPvs() {
            return pvs;
        }
        /**
         * @param pvs the pvs to set
         */
        public void setPvs(Privillages pvs) {
            this.pvs = pvs;
        }
    }
```

**Privillages.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "privillages")
public class Privillages implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer id;
@Column(name="pname")
public String pname;


@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "pid", referencedColumnName = "privid")
public Users pid;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}


@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="privillages")
private Users user;

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "pname")
public String getPname() {
    return pname;
}
public void setPname(String pname) {
    this.pname = pname;
}

@Column(name = "pid")
public Users getPid() {
    return pid;
}
public void setPid(Users pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public Privillages(){
} 
}
```

**Query:**

```
@Query("select u.username from users u inner join u.privillages pr where pr.pname = :pname")
```

Comment: Ok,Thank you for your response sir . I will try.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have added some explanation

Comment: I tried but it shows "org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [pname] [select u.username from Users u inner join u.privillages pr where pr.pname = :pname];" error at runtime.In which direction I need to go for this solution?. And also I need to fetch pname along with username from database.I am trying to fetch all data . Not for any parameter like any name. I am in learning of JPA,New to spring.Trying to make an example of these.

Comment: please change the query-                                                                      
@Query("select u.username from Users u inner join u.privillages pr where pr.pname = :pname")

Comment: Its not getting columns from two tables.

Comment: Yes.Tried.Its working. Previously I have another problem also.And I solved that too. Your previous query is also adapting my requirements.Thank you for your response for guiding me to proper way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must choose if you put your annotations on fields or on setters. Specification requires picking just one way.

You can omit `@Column` annotations, there are default values, so for now let us leave it as it follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public Integer privid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pid")
    private Collection<Privillages> privilages;

    //getters setters
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "privillages")
public class Privillages implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer id;

    public String pname;


    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Users pid;

}
```

Now you can create the following repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    List<User> findAllByUsername(String username);
}
```

method `findAllByUsername` will return a list of Users with certain username.

In case you'd like to stick to the `@Query` remember, that `@Table` annotation doesn't change `@Entity` name, so in your query, reference to `User`, not `Users`.